# How to insert missing months into table of monthly totals

Tags: sas

I have a data set with some monthly sales totals:

```
year month sales
2011 01     100
2011 03     200
2011 04     300
```

Some months (like February 2011 above) had no sales and therefore don't show up in the totals. How can I insert them with a `sales` of zero? Like this:

```
year month sales
2011 01    100
2011 02      0
2011 03    200
2011 04    300
2011 05      0
.
.
.
2011 12      0
```

can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We usually encourage people to include some code showing what they've tried. This helps to narrow the scope down and gives us the opportunity to point out what you are doing incorrectly.

Comment: I strongly suggest improving your question title; "manipulate values" is largely meaningless, all data step work is manipulating values.  Think of what someone googling your problem would put into google.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way to get to that is probably a join to a complete dataset.  IE:

```
data have;
input year month sales;
datalines;
2011 01     100
2011 03     200
2011 04     300
;;;;
run;

data complete;
year=2011;
do month=1 to 12;
output;
end;
run;

data want;
merge complete have;
by year month;
run;
```

In the WANT dataset you can then set sales to 0 or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for comments and answer Cyborgx37 and Joe. I would definitely ask next question with more clarification. Thanks again!!